# Vectorized method find value in dataframe and then use comparison of previous row's value of same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Sample Data

Siutation 1:

```
DateTime         Value1   Value2
8/15/2022 10:47  0.00151    0
8/15/2022 10:48  0.0016     1
8/15/2022 10:49  0.00168    1
```

Situation 2:

```
DateTime         Value1   Value2
8/16/2022 13:38  0.00163    1
8/16/2022 13:39  0.0016     0
8/16/2022 13:40  0.00157    0
```

What I am trying to do:

- Find where Value1 == 0.0016
- If Value1.shift(1) <= Value1, then change Value2 to 0
- If Value1.shift(1) > Value1, then change Value2 to 1

I can do this with lambda or loops.  But I want a way to vectorize the code as there are many rows.

I tried:

```
df['Value3'] = df['Value1'].diff()
df['Value2'] = np.where((df['Value1'] == 0.0016) & (df['Value3'] <= 0 ),0,
               np.where((df['Value1'] == 0.0016) & (df['Value3'] >  0 ),1,np.nan))
```

I also Tried:

```
df['Value2'] = np.where((df['Value1'] == 0.0016) & (df['Value1'].shift(1) <= 0.0016 ),0,
               np.where((df['Value1'] == 0.0016) & (df['Value1'].shift(1) >  0.0016 ),1,np.nan))
```

But as you know, neither approach worked.  Both resulted in all rows being 'nan'.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) and masks:

```
mask1 = df.Value1==0.0016
mask2 = df.Value1.shift(1) > df.Value1

df.loc[mask1 & mask2, 'Value2'] = 1
df.loc[mask1 & ~mask2, 'Value2'] = 0
```